# JQgrid set ondblclick to navigation to new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have a very simple jQgrid i am using for a website

```
            <div id="catalogueSearchList" class="dataGrid">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var catalogueSearchListConfig = {
                        id: 'catalogueSearchList',
                        action: 'List',
                        controller: 'Catalogue',
                        //href: '/Jobs/Adverts/',
                        onDblClick: function (id) { HERE!!! }) },
                        colNames: ['Name', 'CatalogueType'],
                        colModel: [
                                    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 400, align: 'left' },
                                    { name: 'Catalogue type', index: 'CatalogueType', width: 175, align: 'left' },
                        ],
                        sortName: 'Name',
                        sortOrder: 'asc'
                    };
                </script>
            </div>
```

Where it displays "HERE!!!" what can I put here to allow when a viewer double clicks a value in the jqgrid it will navigate them to another page?

Answer (score 0):

Its ok, the answer is

```
<div id="catalogueSearchList" class="dataGrid">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var catalogueSearchListConfig = {
                        id: 'catalogueSearchList',
                        action: 'List',
                        controller: 'Catalogue',
                        //href: '/Jobs/Adverts/',
                        onDblClick: function (id) { window.location.href = "/Catalogue/Category/" + id },
                        colNames: ['Name', 'CatalogueType'],
                        colModel: [
                                    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 400, align: 'left' },
                                    { name: 'Catalogue type', index: 'CatalogueType', width: 175, align: 'left' },
                        ],
                        sortName: 'Name',
                        sortOrder: 'asc'
                    };
                </script>
            </div>
```

Using javascript you can just select the window and set it's location to what you like :)